# Angular, how to show the dropdown items at dropdown button*

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular8

I have a question about dropdown buttons. Here is my code that I copied from an example;

```
        <!--adjustbtn is a class that I made that gives some css to button-->
        <button class="dropdown adjustbtn" style="border-radius: 5px; box-shadow: none;">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" 
            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="color:white">
                Dropdown Button
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
            </div>
        </button>
```

In the example, this was working fine, but when I click the button, nothing pops down from it? What did I miss in here, should I have to code some typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires `js` files to trigger the toggle events of the dropdown.

Please read here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/download/#npm

in `angular.json`, add relative paths of `bootstrap.js` (if needed `jQuery.js` and `popper.js` also) from `node_modules` directory in `scripts` array.

```
{ //.....
   architect: { //....
      build: { //.....
         options: { //....
              "scripts": [
                        "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
                        "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
                        "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
                    ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```